# How can I make application use both SSL and TLS

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

Our java application presently uses SSL for communication between client and server using https. Customer requested if an upgrade can be done to TLS and if they can use both TLS and SSL at different locations. I cant understand clearly how to answer their questions or how to proceed.

jetty-ssl.xml file is as follows :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Configure SSL for the Jetty Server                              -->
<!-- this configuration file should be used in combination with      -->
<!-- other configuration files.  e.g.                                -->
<!--    java -jar start.jar etc/jetty.xml etc/jetty-ssl.xml          -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
        <Set name="Port">8443</Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
        <Set name="handshakeTimeout">2000</Set>
        <Set name="keystore">/xservices-config/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="password">password</Set>
        <Set name="keyPassword">password</Set>
        <Set name="truststore">/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="trustPassword">password</Set>
        <Set name="handshakeTimeout">2000</Set>
        <!-- Set name="ThreadPool">
          <New class="org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool">
            <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
            <Set name="maxThreads">250</Set>
         </New>
        </Set -->
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>  
</Configure>
```

Please let me know how to implement it.

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense. TLS is the successor to SSL, but in practice people use the term interchangeably.  Are they asking to support a newer version of TLS, like 1.2?

Comment: Please be more careful with your passwords!

Comment: @vcsjones : They just asked if they can run with both TLS and SSL. I need to confirm with them if they want to support a new version. If they want to support a new version. Can I make it to use both?

Comment: Well broadly speaking, they are the same thing. (Specifically, they note two different versions of the protocol). Almost any web server today that supports SSL is using TLS and SSL.

Comment: @vcsjones Thanks!! I have read the same thing in most of the websites but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need to "enable" this? I just went back at the jetty documentation and figured, as long as you don't exclude a protocol, you're allowing them all. Check your installation either with a local tool (sslscan, nmap, etc.) or a web application (e.g. from Qualys or COMODO).

If you find with the above analysis that you don't have the versions running, you could use an Apache webserver as HTTPS end-point and mod_proxy the content to jetty.

If that above is your SSL configuration for jetty, I strongly recommend you to harden it! Exclude legacy SSL protocols (e.g. SSLv2) and weak ciphers! As others have mentioned SSLv3 is actually legacy as well and not recommended anymore. In your position, I would get back to your client and check why he wants to have SSLv3 running. Unless he isn't expecting connections from dead old systems (e.g. Win XP with IE), there is not much of a reason to have SSLv3 running. However, if he does not know who is connecting to his page with what browsers, have a look at the logs. If the logs don't show an indication of the web browser used to connect to the application, I strongly recommend to enable it, run it for a period and then take a decision.

Comment: The above configuration is for Jetty 6, long long ago marked as EOL (End of Life).  Even Jetty 7 (switched from org.mortbay.jetty to org.eclipse.jetty) and Jetty 8 are now EOL.  Jetty 9, the current stable, mature, supported branch applies [all of the recommended exclusions out of the box](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.10.v20150310/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.java#L226).  Even the [latest versions of Java disable SSLv3 by default now](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u76-relnotes-2389087.html).